# Matlab: Get neighboring coordinate values - && Operand

Tags: matlab, matrix, coordinate, operand

I'm trying to extract from a 2-D matrix with id values the neighboring ids of each element on the board.

I have a list of of IDs and their coordinates (of n elements), and I'm creating the following:
(Example for left neighbor only).

```
%Left:
leftIndex = (currentLocationIndex - bSize);
hasLeft = leftIndex >= 1; %If element on first col, value will be 0 or negative
hasLeft = hasLeft(:) & board(leftIndex)==0;
```

I get:
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

I want to use the pricipal of && operand or some other logic.
the leftIndex contains all the indices left to a current index in the table.
Some are legal some arn't. If hasLeft vector is true then the leftIndex vector value is legal in the 'board'.

How can I check for a neighbor in a certain value of the vector only if the hasLeft is true?

Thanks!

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol) for [the generic solution to this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054048/983722).

Comment: I've uploaded the project to git: https://github.com/guywald/allele_fixation

Answer (score 2):

I would do two things:

First, find "all the neighbors" including the "illegal" ones. For example, if the indices are `n, m` then all "potential neighbors" are `[pn pm]= meshgrid(n+(-1:1), m+(-1:1));`. Note this also includes the point itself.

Second, mask out only "legal" neighbors by testing their value against the limits of the array. If you have a 2D array with size N by M, you could use

```
legal = find(pn>0 && pn <= N && pm > 0 && pm <= M && ~(pn==n && pm==m));
```

That should give you (up to 8) all legal neighbors. Obviously if you don't want the "kitty corner" neighbors you change the statement that created `pn` and `pm`. I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your question more carefully, and answering only what you asked for (which became clearer after I had read some of your other recent questions...):

The first problem you run into is the fact that your array `leftIndex` may contain values < 1, and therefore cannot legally be used in the expression `hasLeft = hasLeft(:) & board(leftIndex)==0;`

To get around this, you neeed to index `board` with only "valid" indices, which you can get by changing the previous line to

```
hasLeft = find(leftIndex >= 1);
```

Note that your original, `hasLeft = leftIndex >= 0;` generates a logical array of "true" and "false" values of the same size as `leftIndex`. By contrast, the `find` command returns only the indices of the elements that meet the criteria.  Now we need to do two more things: 1) find the elements in `board` with a valid index and a value >=0; and 2) map these back to the index of the "whole thing" (not the index in the subarray). Here is how you do it:

```
interestingSquare = (board(hasLeft)==0);
hasLeft = hasLeft(interestingSquare);
```

This last line takes you back from "position of an interesting square in the sub-array 'hasLeft'" to "position relative to the original `leftIndex` array.

I do wonder whether you really meant to test for `board == 0` but I'm sure that if that was a typo, you would figure it out...

Answer (score 1):

my approach for solving this issue was using the “try” statement
to determent if an index is legal and then assign it, if it is.

this is the closest thing I found to a straightforward check index legality command.

here is a code to illustrate

initialization

```
M=4;  N=5;             
Mat=rand(M,N);
m=2; n=1;
```

the code: try to access this element... assign the element as a legal Neighbor only if Succeeded

```
near= [m,n-1;m,n+1;m+1,n;m-1,n]; 
Neibs=[];          

for i =1:4
    try
        Mat(near(i,1),near(i,2));  
        Neibs=[Neibs;[near(i,1),near(i,2)]]; 
    catch
    end
end
```

results presentation

```
BW=zeros(M,N);
if ~isempty(Neibs)
    for i =1:length(Neibs(:,1))
        BW(Neibs(i,1),Neibs(i,2))=true;
    end
end
```

of course once the point is made, changing the size,
dimensions, or neighborhood metrica is not a problem